# Social media icons not aligns Vertically instead of Horizontally

Tags: html, css

Trying to have the sidebar icons show up horizontally; they show up as vertically for me.
I don't understand too well what I copy and pasted for the CSS to be honest, but I just wanted the list at the top like navbar and just a sidebar that I copy and paste on each page to always have social media links.
//Valentines Project if you couldn't tell//

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700');

body {

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

    display: flex;

    justify-content: center;

    align-items: top center;

    height: auto;

    background: #333;

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}



ul {

    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

    display: flex;

}



ul li {

    list-style: none;

    margin: 0 20px;

    transition: 0.5s;

}



ul li a {
    top: 10%;

    display: block;

    position: relative;

    text-decoration: none;

    padding: 5px;

    font-size: 25px;

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

    font-weight: bold;

    color: #fff;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    transition: 0.5s;

}



ul:hover li a {

    transform: scale(1.5);

    opacity: .2;

    filter: blur(5px);

}



ul li a:hover {

    transform: scale(2);

    opacity: 1;

    filter: blur(0);

}



ul li a:before {

    content: '';

    position: absolute;

    top: 0;

    left: 0;

    width: 100%;

    height: 100%;

    background: #ff497c;

    transition: transform 0.5s;

    transform-origin: right;

    transform: scale(0);

    z-index: -1;

}



ul li a:hover:before {

    transition: transform 0.5s;

    transform-origin: left;

    transform: scaleX(1);

}

.sidebar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0%;
}

#katy-fb {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(/doodle-bop/Assets/icons/katy-fb.png);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}

#geo-fb {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(/doodle-bop/Assets/icons/geo-fb.png);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}

#katy-twit {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(/doodle-bop/Assets/icons/katy-twit.png);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}

#geo-twit {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(/doodle-bop/Assets/icons/geo-twit.png);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}

#insta {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url(/doodle-bop/Assets/icons/instagram.png);
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/doodle-bop/Code/Styles/index.css">
  <title>Katy and Geo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">what</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="social-icons">
      <a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="icon" id="insta"></span></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="icon" id="geo-twit"></span></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="#"> 
      <span class="icon" id="geo-fb"></span></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="#"><span class="icon" id="katy-twit"></span></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="#"> 
      <span class="icon" id="katy-fb"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To begin with, your markup is incorrect. All div tags should be inside of the body tags. Basically, start by moving your sidebar div into your body tags then you can start to look at styling them correctly.

Comment: I'll do so, is it just bad practice or is it harmful to the code?

Comment: It's just correct structure to place all your tags in the body. It's just like writing a paragraph, you have to make sure your sentences have proper structure and punctuation. Looking at the code above you have your sidebar with a width = 0, that won't show up anywhere. How do you get your sidebar to show at all?